# Is it possible to assign a captured group from a Powershell regex to a variable without an IF block?

Tags: regex, powershell, match, capture-group

I have this code:

```ps
$text = "blah blah blah, yada yada yada, foobar"
If ($text -match '^.*(?<found>foobar).*$') {
    $foundtext = $Matches.found
}
$foundtext
```

But I want to know how to do the equivalent of this:

```ps
$text = "blah blah blah, yada yada yada, foobar"
$foundtext = ($text -match '^.*(?<found>foobar).*$').found
$foundtext
```

That is, I want to know if I can assign the captured group from the regex straight to a variable without having to wrap it in an IF statement. The problem is that the `$text -match '^.*(?<found>foobar).*$'` regex match code evaluates to a `$True` or `$False`.

To word it more colloquially, I want the code to say "*set the variable `$foundtext` equal to the captured group named `found` in the expression `($text -match '^.*(?<found>foobar).*$')`*"

Is this possible?
Is so, what is the correct syntax?

Comment: It's already assigned to `$Matches`, so just use `$Matches['found']` (or `$Matches.found`) directly if you're sure there's always a match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Mathias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68361564/is-it-possible-to-assign-a-captured-group-from-a-powershell-regex-to-a-variable#comment120817823_68361564) already commented, you can use `$Matches` to get the value.

If you want to get the matched value in a single line of code, you can also do this:

```
$text = "blah blah blah, yada yada yada, foobar"

# using the capture groups index:
$foundtext = ([regex]'(?i)^.*(?<found>foobar).*$').Match($text).Groups[1].Value

# or by the capture group's Name:
$foundtext = ([regex]'(?i)^.*(?<found>foobar).*$').Match($text).Groups['found'].Value
```

<sup>`(?i)` makes the regex work case-insensitive like `-match`</sup>